# How can I copy a file from remote computer (same network) to my local computer using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to copy a file from a remote computer to local computer using PowerShell. I checked many posts to get answer to this but I am confused now. Somewhere it is mentioned to use Invoke-Command somewhere enabling WSManCredSSP. The script is available in my local machine and I cannot do any changes in the remote computer.

Please help.

Regards,

Mitesh Agrawal

Comment: Are both machines part of the same domain and are you the domain admin? Or do you have an account on the remote machine?

Comment: Both are in the same domain and I have a domain user to run the script. Also, please let me know what permission are required for this user.

Comment: As a domain admin you can access any file easily through the hidden shares for example. You can access the `C:\ ` drive of your remote computer like this: `\\REMOTECOMPUTERNAME\C$\...` and use these paths in regular copy commands.

Comment: Use the UNC path on the remote computer. Something like `Copy-Item -Path '\\ComputerName\C$\Folderpath\FileToCopy.txt' -Destination 'C:\Temp'`

Comment: Ok. So there won't be any need to use WSManCredSSP and complicate the requirement right?